# angularjs resource not making any api calls

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-service, ngresource

Below is my resource call, but it is never making any call. I cannot see a request in my server. What i am doing wrong here?

myfactory:

```
userAccountApp.factory('dataSer',function($resource)
{
   uData = {} 
   uData.Users = $resource('/url/getusers/', {},   {'query':{method: 'GET', isArray: true }});

  return uData
})
```

controller:

```
userAccountApp.controller('getCtrl', function($scope,dataSer)
{
   data = dataSer.Users()
   console.log(data)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this :

```
userAccountApp.controller('getCtrl', function($scope,dataSer)
{
   dataSer.Users.query(function(data){
       console.log(data)
   })

})
```

Write your logic inside callback function.